# Creating a User in Keycloak 21.1.1 using Service Access Token

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm working with Keycloak version 21.1.1 and I have a client that has been granted a **service access token**. I would like to use this token to create a new user programmatically. How can I create a user in Keycloak using the service access token?

Here's what I have tried so far:

Obtained the service access token for my client.
Made a POST request to the Keycloak API /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users endpoint with the necessary user data and included the service access token in the Authorization header.
However, I'm receiving an **"403"** when trying to create the user.

Could you please provide guidance on the correct approach to create a user using the service access token in Keycloak 21.1.1? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have found that, i have to assign manage-users permission to my client.
don't know how to do it in keycloak 21.1.1

Answer (score 0):

using code, we have created user in our spring boot application like below,

maven dependancy,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>21.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Note:** we have used the saml identity provider which you can remove from below code if your not using it.

```
public class KeycloakServiceClient {

   private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KeycloakServiceClient.class);

   private static final String SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER = "saml";

   @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
   private String keycloakRealmName;

   public void setKeycloakRealmName(String keycloakRealmName) {
      this.keycloakRealmName = keycloakRealmName;
   }

   private final Keycloak keycloak;

   @Autowired
   public KeycloakServiceClient(Keycloak keycloak) {
      this.keycloak = keycloak;
   }

   public void addUserToKeycloakWithRetry(String userId, String firstName, String lastName) {
      addUserToKeycloak(userId, firstName, lastName);
   }

   public Boolean addUserToKeycloak(String userId, String firstName, String lastName) {
      boolean isUserAdded = false;

      UserRepresentation keycloakUser = new UserRepresentation();
      keycloakUser.setEnabled(true);
      keycloakUser.setUsername(userId);
      keycloakUser.setFirstName(firstName);
      keycloakUser.setLastName(lastName);

      UsersResource usersResource = keycloak.realm(keycloakRealmName).users();

      try (Response response = usersResource.create(keycloakUser)) {
         addIdentityProviderLink(usersResource, userId);

         if (response != null) {
            switch (response.getStatus()) {
               case HttpStatus.SC_CREATED:
                  LOG.info("New user added to keycloak, userId:{}", userId);
                  break;
               case HttpStatus.SC_CONFLICT:
                  LOG.info("Failed to add user to keycloak due to data conflict. The username or email is reused. userId:{}", userId);
                  break;
               case HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN:
                  LOG.error("Access to the requested resource in keycloak is forbidden");
                  break;
               default:
                  LOG.warn("Failed to add new user to keycloak userId: {}, responseStatus: {}", userId,
                           response.getStatus());
                  break;
            }

            isUserAdded = HttpStatus.SC_CREATED == response.getStatus() ? true : false;
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         LOG.error(e.getMessage());
         throw e;
      }

      return isUserAdded;
   }

   // it needed for saml identity provider
   private void addIdentityProviderLink(UsersResource usersResource, String userId) {
      UserRepresentation userRepresentation = usersResource.list(0, -1).stream()
               .filter(usr -> usr.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(userId)).findAny().orElse(null);

      if (userRepresentation != null) {
         FederatedIdentityRepresentation federatedIdentityRepresentation = new FederatedIdentityRepresentation();
         federatedIdentityRepresentation.setIdentityProvider(SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER);
         federatedIdentityRepresentation.setUserId(userRepresentation.getUsername());
         federatedIdentityRepresentation.setUserName(userRepresentation.getUsername());

         usersResource.get(userRepresentation.getId()).addFederatedIdentity(SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER,
                  federatedIdentityRepresentation);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm using REST Api, not adapters.
And I don't want to use admin-cli, instead i have created a client "IdentityService" and using Service Access Token.

Comment: your client need manage-realm permission, then it should work

Comment: how to give permissions to client in Keycloak 21.1.1?
and if you can suggest any tutorials about Keycloak 21.1.1?!

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_fine_grain_permissions